# Move from child fragment to other child fragment from option menu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-navhostfragment

Hi have a navigation component with 4 destination, and I add that destination in an option menu.

It works perfectly, but now I need to move from a selected fragment to another one, but I didn't found any solution, because I can open my selected fragment, but I can't reopen the first one.

This is the configuration of nav controller in MainActivity:

```
val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    setOf(
        R.id.nav_home,
        R.id.nav_two,
        R.id.nav_three,
        R.id.nav_four
    ), drawerLayout
)

navController?.let {
    setupActionBarWithNavController(it, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(it)
}
```

This is the (wrong) call in second fragment to go programmatically to go to forth fragment:

```
requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_four)
```

Like I say, I go correctly to fourth fragment, but navigation not work correctly, because after that it's impossible to select home fragment selection in side menu.

Any solutions?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't [following the documentation to tie a menu item to the NavController](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#Tie-navdrawer)?

Comment: I solve it! I send my solution in a moment

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider you have my_navigation.xml file, and you added 4 fragments fragment_1, fragment_2, fragment_3 and fragment_4 respectively.
You should add paths between each fragment.

- from fragment_1 to fragment_2, fragment_3, fragment_4
- from fragment_2 to fragment_1, fragment_3, fragment_4
- from fragment_3 to fragment_1, fragment_2, fragment_4
- from fragment_4 to fragment_1, fragment_2, fragment_3

So, you can navigate from any fragment to any fragment with actionID.

[ref: https://medium.com/swlh/android-navigation-component-part-1-6191323eaf39](https://medium.com/swlh/android-navigation-component-part-1-6191323eaf39)

from any fragment, you can navigate to another fragment like this:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.yourActionID_that_your_write_in_myNavigation_xml_file)
```

I might misunderstood the question, if it is, please update me.
Good Luck!

Comment: Too many line of code maybe, I found a more elegant solution, I'm sharing it :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that solution, under navigator code in main activity just add:

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when(item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_home)
        }
        R.id.nav_one -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_one)
        }
        R.id.nav_two -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_two)
        }
        R.id.nav_three -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_three)
        }
    }
//And if you want to close drawer
//drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    true
}
```